# With CoreData is it OK to have multiple contexts on the same thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

With CoreData, is it OK to have multiple contexts on the same thread?  At work we are debating whether having multiple contexts on the main thread can cause deadlock.  I can't find any reason not to do it, but I am concerned that when one of the main thread contexts saves and merges into the other main thread context it may cause deadlock.

Note there appears to be a related ticket that is actually NOT related at all: [Multiple contexts in the main thread: why and when use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091375/multiple-contexts-in-the-main-thread-why-and-when-use-them)  This ticket ONLY discusses using multiple contexts in general, and what a context is, and does not actually ever discuss any issues with using multiple contexts on the same thread.

Comment: For thread safe coredata object, there should be one context per thread.

Comment: Where did you find this in the documentation!?  I see lots of documentation saying that each context must only be accessed on one thread--but that, of course is the opposite of what I am asking.  I'm asking about multiple contexts on one thread--so that each context is only accessed on the thread on which it was created--but both on the same thread.  Please share a link!?

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html

and look here too

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

If you choose not to use the thread containment pattern—that is, if you try to pass managed objects or contexts between threads, and so on—you must be extremely careful about locking, and as a consequence you are likely to negate any benefit you may otherwise derive from multi-threading. You also need to consider that:

Any time you manipulate or access managed objects, you use the associated managed object context.
Core Data does not present a situation where reads are “safe” but changes are “dangerous”—every operation is “dangerous” because every operation has cache coherency effects and can trigger faulting.

Managed objects themselves are not thread safe.
If you want to work with a managed object across different threads, you must lock its context.

Comment: Your answer specifically talks about using multiple threads.  I'm specifically interested in only using one thread.  How does your answer relate to the question? What am I missing here?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but you said "does not actually ever discuss any issues with using multiple contexts on the same thread", so I was trying to explain the issue with multiple context in a thread.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are talking about passing managed objects between threads. I'm talking about only using the main thread or one thread.  Essentially, I'm talking about NOT using multiple-threads.  So, I'm not asking about thread safety in anyway.   What I'm asking about is avoiding multiple threads, but still using multiple contexts on just one thread.